# How do I search for Shared Drive by name

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to get to Shared Drive by its name and not by ID
Using the `DriveApp.getFolderById ()` method, I get to Shared Drive and create new folders or give permissions.
But when I try to use the method: `DriveApp.getFoldersByName (name)`
I can't get to Shared Drive and set up folders or give permissions.
Is it possible to search Shared Drive by name in another way?
Thanks

code :

```
 var Drive_Name=DriveApp.getFoldersByName('SharedDrive_name')

  var Folder_1=parentFolder.createFolder("test_1")
  var Folder_2=parentFolder.createFolder("test_2")
  var Folder_3=parentFolder.createFolder("test_3")`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) and the search query "`q`". Also, don't forget to use the parameter `supportsAllDrives` (which will be deprecated in June 1 2020), otherwise it won't search among your Shared Drives.

```
function test() {

  var query = 'title = "SharedDrive_name"';

  var folder = Drive.Files.list({q: query, supportsAllDrives:true});

  Logger.log(folder);

}
```

For some reason Apps Script uses Drive V2, which uses "title" instead of "name".